# Change url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

http://localhost/project_name/folder1/index.php/folder2/controller

I want to change my url to using htaccess-

http://localhost/project_name/controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code inside root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can change the route url in Codeigniter. 
Application->config->routes.php

```
$route['controller']='folder1/index.php/folder2/controller';
```

Comment: This is just removing the index.php from the url.I want to remove the folder names as well.

Comment: @ReshamDeshpande You can change the route url in Codeigniter.

Application->config->routes.php

$route['controller']='folder1/index.php/folder2/controller';

Answer (score 1):

Activate the URL-rewrite module in apache and then write rewrite rules according to your preferred behaviour.

The rules for the rewrite module can be quite tricky and complex so I can really only refer you to their own documentation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Write your base_url in config file. 
after that remove "index.php" from config file

```
i.e.$config['index_page'] = '';

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```